# Angular UI update on Database Change

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an angular application which is getting data from a backend asp.net core web-API. Multiple users are logged into the application. Whoever user performs a specific action first, takes control. The application goes into read only mode for the other logged in users.

When other users refresh the page they will see new changes. I am wondering if there is a better way to update the UI for other users without refreshing the page.

I am currently think of polling the web-API from the angular application in an interval and update the UI. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ASP.NET Core, SignalR sounds like a good option for you. Here the description from the official docs:

> ASP.NET Core SignalR is an open-source library that simplifies adding
>   real-time web functionality to apps. Real-time web functionality
>   enables server-side code to push content to clients instantly.

Official docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2

NPM package for using it with your app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

> ASP.NET Core SignalR is an open-source library that simplifies adding real-time web functionality to apps. Real-time web functionality enables server-side code to push content to clients instantly.